Triple integral in spherical coordinates over a tetrahedron
Happy New Year!
I am trying to evaluate a triple integral where the domain $T$ is the tetrahedron with its vertices at $(0, 0, 0)$, $(2, 0, 0)$, $(2, 2, 0)$, and $(2, 0, 2)$.
I am trying to express the integral as repeated integrals using spherical coordinates.
My problem is: does $\rho$ go from $0$ to the surface $x=2$, $\phi$ from $\frac\pi4$ to $\frac\pi2$, and $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac\pi4$?
Thanks for any help.

First you have to specify the role of each of your spherical coordinates. Are you using math conventions where $\phi$ is colatitude measured down from the pole and $\theta$ is the longitude measured around the equator? Or physics conventions that has these swapped? In other words, is $z = \rho\cos\phi$ (math) or is $z = \rho\cos\theta$ (physics)?

Hi ,thanks for the edits ,am very poor at this.I am using the math version

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3335411/170231

Thanks for your help,I think I got the lower limit for $\phi$ wrong,I think it’s found by substituting spherical coordinates into the equation of the sloping plane z=x-y,as that’s the first time a $rho$ line goes through the tetrahedron.

The region condition is
     RegionConvert[ 
         Simplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 2}}],
         "Implicit"]

          ImplicitRegion[x >= y + z && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && 
           x <= 2, {x, y, z}]

$$0\leq z\leq 2\land ((0\leq y<2-z\land y+z\leq x\leq 2)\lor (y=2-z\land x=2))$$
I don't think that it's possible to solve for the domain in  $(r,\xi,\eta)$ by $$x\to r \ \xi \ \sqrt{1-\eta^2}, y \to r \sqrt{1-\xi^2} \ \sqrt{1-\eta^2}, z \to r \ \eta $$ with $\xi, \eta$ representing the sines of the angles in spherical coordinates.
The cartesian integrals are trivial, eg the center of gravity is
$$\frac{\int_0^2 \left(\int_0^x \left(\int_0^{x-y} \{x,y,z\} \, dz\right) \, dy\right) \, dx}{\int_0^2 \left(\int_0^x \left(\int_0^{x-y} 1 \, dz\right) \, dy\right) \, dx} = \left\{\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$
coinciding with Mathematica
 Integrate[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
   Simplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 2}}]]/
 Integrate[  1, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
   Simplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 2}}]]

If you prefer spherical coordinates, choose $(2,2,0)$ as origin and the symmetry axis from $(2,2,0)$ to $(0,2,2)$ as the new z-polar axis with rotional symmetry by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ for the former cartesian axes.

Please use more words and not the symbols $\wedge$ and $\vee$ in writing mathematics. And learn basic MathJax, please: write \le, \ge, and so on for inequalities. Also, no one said the OP wanted to calculate the volume of the tetrahedron. Last, and most important, I do not agree with your analysis of the region.
